# How do I find all instances of related to a value in a another cell- EXCEL 2013

Tags: excel, duplicates, excel-2013

I'm stuck with the captioned and I'm not sure how to proceed.

Problem statement: I have 2 columns. Column A contains names that may repeat. Column B contains dates (DD-MMM-YY). Now I need to highlight/find/mark all cases where a particular name in column A has 2 dates a week/7days apart in column B.

Illustration:

[image: Example of data that needs to be marked]

In the above image only Jack and Genea should be highlighted/found/marked as they occur more than once and have dates in column B that are a week apart.

Could this be solved by using Formulas or VBA? Any leads, hints, tips, illustrations would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This can be done with Conditional formatting.

Comment: If you had entries for Jack on the 6th, 9th and 13th, would that still be highlighted? The 6th and the 13th are over a week apart, but neither is a week away from the 9th...  In other words, is this the difference between the `MIN` and `MAX` dates, or when the largest gap between *sequential* dates is over a week?

Comment: @ScottCraner a week apart? how?

Comment: @Chronocidal no, they should be exactly 1 week apart.

Comment: @FloydFernandes Okay, what if Genea had 7th March, 14th March and 28th March:  Should all 3 be highlighted, or just the first 2 entries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on clarifications in comments, there are potentially 4 different answers here.  If the requirement is to highlight rows for the same Person who are *exactly* 7 days apart, regardless of whether there is another entry that fits between them (e.g. **Sunday** - Wednesday - **Sunday**), then you can just use this:

```
=(COUNTIFS(A:A, A1, B:B, B1+7) + COUNTIFS(A:A, A1, B:B, B1-7))>1
```

This will check for any rows where the Name matches the current `{Row Name}`, and the Date is exactly the current `{Row Date}` ± 7

If you *can't* have any dates between the rows, then it gets slightly more complicated.  If you have Office 365 or Office 2019, then you can use the `MINIFS` and `MAXIFS` functions to find the next date up or down

```
=OR(MINIFS(B:B, A:A, A1, B:B, ">" & B1)=(B1+7), MAXIFS(B:B, A:A, A1, B:B, "<" & B1)=(B1-7))
```

If you have an older version of Office, you will need to replace `MINIFS` and `MAXIFS` with an Array Formula:

```
=OR(SUMPRODUCT(MIN(B:B+9999*(1-(A:A=A1)*--(B:B>B1))))=B1+7, SUMPRODUCT(MAX(B:B*--(A:A=A1)*--(B:B<B1)))=B1-7)
```

(You'll notice that the ability to "zero out" the values makes our `MAXIFS` substitute simpler than our `MINIFS` one, where we are adding `9999` as our discard method)

For the last 2 cases, where you want to highlight ALL rows for an individual when either of those other conditions is matched for *any* of their rows, then you need a **far** more complicated Array Formula.

Comment: Thank you so much. The third option worked for me since I'm using the 2013 version of excel. I'm trying to learn how you came to that solution and I see that you have used SUMPRODUCT and MIN functions. Is there any other concept you used in this answer that I could learn?

Comment: The `SUMPRODUCT` allows us to use an Array Formula in a normal formula.  You can find information about Array Formulae [here](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7#ID0EAAEAAA=Office_2013_-_Office_2019) (official Microsoft documentation, but not particularly clear), [here](https://www.excel-easy.com/functions/array-formulas.html) (better illustrated and easier to understand, but more basic), or [here](https://exceljet.net/glossary/array-formula) (somewhere between the two).

Comment: @FloydFernandes Other than that, it's just a case of breaking the problem down into smaller and smaller chunks of a step-by-step guide, until the Computer can understand it.

Comment: Thanks @Chronocidal you are really a very helpful person. I appreciate it. I will go through the links and try to learn more about it. I am trying to work on something a little more complicated. I hope I can reach out to you if I have doubts.